Docker API build does not reuse layers from cache
I have a Dockerfile, and when I run docker build from the command line it reuses unchanged layers as expected. However, when I start the build using the Python API, it always rebuilds all steps. Any idea what the problem could be? My code looks like this:
import docker

with contextlib.closing(docker.from_env()) as client:
    stream = client.api.build(path=workdir, tag=newtag, rm=True)
    for part in stream:
        # process stream
        print(part)


Explanation
docker library does not currently support BuildKit, see this thread for more information.
BuildKit is "an improved backend to replace the legacy builder. BuildKit is the default builder for users on Docker Desktop, and Docker Engine as of version 23.0."
Because the build backend is different, docker cannot reuse the cache between the two different styles.
You can verify this by inspecting the final SHA for the images, they should differ.
Solutions
The cache should populate though after you build it once with your python program. However, if you really want these to work together, you can disable the buildkit and use the legacy builder by doing this:
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build .


Thanks! Unfortunately the problem is not just about mixing docker cli+BuildKit and docker API. Even if I use Docker API just by itself, and run the Python code twice, it doesn't do layer caching.

@jdm well that is strange. Without seeing your Dockerfile I would say that the problem is then with that and there's something changing in the context directory that invalidates it that triggers only when python is running, but hard to say without more information. Might have nothing to do with that also.
